How to input a mathematical formula through code?
I want to generate math courseware through code. At first, I used Java POI, but it does not support adding animations and mathematical formulas. Later, I learned that there are some methods in VBA, but I am not sure if it can add complex mathematical formulas.
I found a method to input mathematical expressions through searching, like this:
Sub WhatIsTheEquationMadeOf()
    Dim x As Long, txtBox As Shape
    word = "Solve "
    
    Set txtBox = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    If txtBox.Type = msoTextBox Then
        With txtBox.TextFrame.TextRange
            .Font.Color = RGB(80, 122, 160)
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
            .Font.Size = 22
            .Text = word & "2x^2+7x+6=0"
            .Characters(Len(word) + 1, .Characters.Count - Len(word)).Select
            With Application.CommandBars
                .ExecuteMso "InsertBuildingBlocksEquationsGallery"
                .ExecuteMso "EquationProfessional"
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub

but I don't know what syntax to use to write other mathematical expressions. For example, a Fraction.

Downvoted for tag spamming.

If you are serious about it then LaTex is probably the most suitable for coding mathematical formulae. The learning curve is quite steep but it can express equations in a form typeset and suitable for professional publications.

You can build other expressions by simply replacing quoted text in the line starting with .Text. Complex expressions may require LaTex, but you mentioned a fraction which can simply be something like (a+3)/b^2 or (x-1)/(x^2-2)

It might be worth looking at the .TextRange2.TextFrame property of each character in an equation you've already entered to see what PowerPoint makes of it. You won't be able to view the characters as a MsgBox or in the debug window but invoke the .Copy method on the TextFrame then paste it into e.g. Notepad.  Here, I get:  (+)^=∑24_(=0)^▒〖(¦) ^ ^(−) 〗 for one of the sample equations.

I found this  and this that may help.

Thank you very much for your replies. The information you provided me was very useful. I tried it out and it worked fine.
